# How to move to next page using selenium webdriver in python until end

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<li title="下一页" class=" rc-pagination-next" 
aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"> 
    <a class="rc-pagination-item-link">==$0
     ::after
    </a>
</li>
```

In the Above code i am unable to click the  to move to the next page.
If somebody could help me would be of great help.

I am writing this script in Python and using selenium chrome webdriver

Comment: Share your code and clarify WHY you're *unable to click*

Comment: @Andersson here is the code that i have written. browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a["@class=rc-pagination-item-link"]').click()

Comment: did faced any exception on execution, plz paste exception also

Comment: @muraliselenium no exception the code went through but in the chrome browser it is not clicking the next button

Comment: maybe you could try another markup: 
browser.find_elements_by_class_name("rc-pagination-item-link")

or

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rc-pagination-item-link")

Comment: @kratze recieved and error while implementing the one you told me which is as follows: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a class="rc-pagination-item-link"></a> is not clickable at point (1500, 196). Other element would receive the click: <li title="上一页" class="rc-pagination-disabled rc-pagination-prev" aria-disabled="true">...</li>

Comment: @sachinsafale and when you change the markup to click on the <li> element instead of the a ? Sorry it is difficult to help, when you dont see the site.

Comment: @kratze i changed the markup to click on <li> and it saved me big time thanks for you help

Comment: @kratze if you could also help me in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208052/stale-exception-error-while-browsing-through-for-loop will mean alot am stuck real bad